# Apache Virtual Host Site Inaccessible

Tags: apache, virtual, hosts

I'm setting up a dedicated server with multiple virtual hosts. The DNS is registered correctly...

```
$ ping mydomain.com
$ ping 8.8.8.8 (for example)
```

Both return the IP address as expected and it's correct.

The last line of my httpd.conf file is:

`Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/`

And the contents of mydomain.com.conf (in the above folder) are:

```
<VirtualHost 8.8.8.8:80>
    ServerName  mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin jongosi@mydomain.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/mydomain.com">
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I suspected that the firewall was interfering with the access so I have disabled it with:

`$ /etc/init.d/iptables stop`

The server is running CentOS 6 64-bit with the latest LAMP stack.

Trying to go to the address `http://www.mydomain.com/` or the IP address in browser both result in eventual time-out. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you!

---

**EDIT 1**

Running `apachectl -S` returns...

```
VirtualHost configuration:
8.8.8.8:80        mydomain.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf:6)
Syntax OK
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Following the request in Chrome's inspector returns a 204 header response.

```
204 No Content
    The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does apache know to traverse a directory `Include`? Usually I have seen stuff `Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/*.conf`

Comment: Well [the documentation allows for `directory-path`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) though none of their examples use it.

Comment: Oh wait, you attempted to use `www.mydomain.com` but you don't have that domain specified.  `ServerAlias www.mydomain.com`

Comment: And do you have a `NameVirtualHost *:80`?

Comment: Hi Michael, no, I don't have `NameVirtualHost *:80` set up - that line is commented out in the httpd.conf file. Tried `*.conf`, no dice. Also added a server alias with `www.mydomain.com` but no dice either. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

My hosting provider had configured their hardware firewall to only allow traffic through on port 22 (SSH). Why on earth would I NOT want traffic on my WEBSITE.

`$_hosting_provider = "In.sane";`